# Как преобразовать данные считаные из .txt файла в list?

Tags: python, парсер, десериализация

У меня есть файл .txt, который представляет из себя что-то вроде:

```
[["o":96.069999999999993,"c":96.549999999999997,"h":96.900000000000006,"l":95.900000000000006,"v":2067,"time":"2021-09-06T07:00:00Z","interval":"5min","figi":"BBG005DXJS36"],["o":96.549999999999997,"c":96.439999999999998,"h":96.640000000000001,"l":95.689999999999998,"v":1344,"time":"2021-09-06T07:05:00Z","interval":"5min","figi":"BBG005DXJS36"]]
```

То есть, имеет вид обычного списка python.

При попытке прочитать его, данные считываются как символы.

Как получить после чтения этого файла обычный список (`list`), а не строку?

Comment: Используйте что-то вроде `json.load()` или `yaml.safe_load()` ;) Дьявол, как обычно, кроется в деталях - чем подробнее и "воспроизводимее" будут примеры данных в вопросе, тем полезнее будут ответы )

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, добавил реальные данные к вопросу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [yaml.safe_load()](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

Пример:

```
from yaml import safe_load   #  pip install pyyaml

with open(filename) as file:
    data = safe_load(file)
```

результат:

```
In [103]: data
Out[103]:
[[{'o': 96.07},
  {'c': 96.55},
  {'h': 96.9},
  {'l': 95.9},
  {'v': 2067},
  {'time': '2021-09-06T07:00:00Z'},
  {'interval': '5min'},
  {'figi': 'BBG005DXJS36'}],
 [{'o': 96.55},
  {'c': 96.44},
  {'h': 96.64},
  {'l': 95.69},
  {'v': 1344},
  {'time': '2021-09-06T07:05:00Z'},
  {'interval': '5min'},
  {'figi': 'BBG005DXJS36'}]]
```